# jQuery UI Droppable & iScroll

Tags: jquery-ui-droppable, iscroll4

I am using iScroll together with jQuery UI Drag&Drop. The iScroll "Scroller"-Div contains 2 children: a zoomable image and a droppable div.

If I Zoom in, the droppable div seems to resize too, so far it's ok. But if I zoom in and try to drop a draggable on the droppable, the functional drop-area remains small like not zoomed in and is positioned in the upper left corner of the zoomed droppable.

I don't know where the problem is and hope you can help me with this.